# Find subgraphs in a directed graph which are isolated by certain properties

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, graph-theory, subgraph

Please excuse my small knowledge of graph theory vocabulary.

I can only describe the problem with common english words. Maybe someone can point me into the right direction and/or terms to look up.

The problem came up as part of the implementation of a visual programming language. Where a vertex is a function/method and the edges transport data between the functions. Now there is the following problem:

It could be allowed to connect the output of vertex A with the type of *Collection< TItem >* to the input of vertex B with type *TItem*. And then the output of vertex B with type *TItem* to the input vertex C with type *Collection< TItem >*. This would tell the compiler that it has to wrap a *foreach* function around vertex B to apply the function of B to each item in the collection from A and output the new items as collection to the input of C. So the edge from A to B is a many to one connection and from B to C is one to many.

Now the actual problem is, what kind of algorithm would find a (directed) subgraph that is surrounded/isolated by one to many connections? so that the compiler would wrap a foreach function around this particular subgraph? I've tried to visualize the problem in this picture:

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid I understand neither what graph you are constructing nor what set you want to find within the graph. Could you maybe abstract more from your problem and describe the graph and the set you want to find without relating it to what you actually want to do? You seem to have different types of vertices and/or edges, coloring will be perfectly fine to differentiate, while the type stuff doesn't help me, personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following algorithm:

**Step 1** Walk through all the nodes. If you find a blue node, do a [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) in the directed graph to find out the set of white nodes reachable from it. Don't cross blue nodes while doing the DFS. Along with the set of nodes, store the starting blue node and the outgoing blue nodes that you discovered during the DFS.

You end up with multiple sets of white nodes, along with information about the incoming and outgoing blue nodes:

[image]

(bear with me, my mouse drawing skills are really bad)

**Step 2** As you can see, you might have overlaps. There are two possibilities to resolve this:

- Merge overlapping sets by using a [disjoint-set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) afterwards. This results in a *O(n² + m)* worst case runtime.
- Avoid creating the overlaps in the first place by modifying the standard DFS algorithm. It should detect when you reach a node that you have already seen in one of the previously explored sets. It should then not explore the subgraph further, but record that the currently explored set and the overlapping one are to be merged later. Afterwards you can find the connected components in the merging graph. This will give you a 
  *O(n + m)* runtime, which is a lot better.

You end up with a collection of disjoint sets of white nodes together with respective incoming and outgoing blue nodes:

[image]

Comment: this is most excellent and pragmatic. the modified depth first search sounds like a practical way to go.

Comment: @thalm: I just noticed that you don't even need a DSU data structure then. If you find an overlap, just remember that you need to merge the two sets later. Afterwards do a second DFS to find the connected components in the merging graph.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that there could be multiple such subgraphs in your graph.

To find each one you visit all the nodes in the graph and count the parents/children to determine whether it is a member of the desired set, then separate out all the marked nodes into their respective subgraphs or *cliques*. General procedures for working with cliques can be found on Wikipedia: [The Clique Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem).

Comment: That seems arbitrary. What about the inner nodes? And cliques don't exist in DAGs like OP's graph is, so what do you mean by that? Also do you realize that Clique finding is an NP-hard problem?

Comment: @NiklasB. Finding a clique is not NP-hard, finding a clique of maximum cardinality is. Also, cliques are defined for undirected graphs.

Comment: @G.Bach: Sure, but OPs path is directed. I think I know what you mean, but you should be a little bit more explicit. But you're right, finding inclusion-maximal cliques is not too hard

Comment: Cliques are not what we need though. We need connected subgraphs

Comment: @NiklasB. Finding just any clique is trivial, finding some inclusion-maximal clique is O(n^2) with a simple approach, and finding a largest clique is NP-hard. I don't see how cliques play any role here since the graph is directed.

Comment: @G.Bach: And especially even after bidirecting the edges, there don't need to be any cliques of size > 2 at all (as it is the case in OPs example).

Comment: The OP wanted to be "pointed in the right direction" and given a "term to look up". That is exactly what I provided.

Comment: @TylerDurden: Care to explain how the concept of a clique is at all relevant here? Note that OPs input graph has no (non-trivial) cliques at all. Also I'm not sure how your isolation criterium helps. For example the two nodes in the middle have no adjacent blue nodes at all but belong to the result set. How to discriminate those from the other white node at the top right which also has no adjacent blue node but is *not* part of the result?

Comment: @Niklas B. the same general procedures that are used to isolate cliques in a graph can be used to pull out the subgraphs which the OP is interested in.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't understand the statement "count the parents/children to determine whether it is a member of the desired set" at all, because the parent/child count is totally orthogonal to whether the node is a member of a subgraph like OP needs to find

Comment: "the same general procedures that are used to isolate cliques in a graph can be used to pull out the subgraphs which the OP is interested in" I am also very unsure about this statement. What do you mean by "general procedure that is used to isolate cliques in a graph"? It's strange because in the answer you say that cliques need to be found, but now you don't?